# Background color to Navbar links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]I have already defined my Navbar and it works perfectly fine, except I want to give a full page background to the Navbar links as well. Currently when I want to open the page on a mobile device, the links background doesn't cover the whole page horizontally, but instead it looks like a highlighted line. For more detail see the screenshots. I would appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thanks!

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#backrondimage"><img src="img/homepage.png" alt="" class="hompagecover"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar4">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsingNavbar4">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#div1" class="navbaritems"> Portfolio </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#div2" class="navbaritems">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#div3" class="navbaritems">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#div4" class="navbaritems">Resume</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a href="mailto:abdullah.ameenn@gmail.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/email.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;border-radius:25px;"></a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/abdullahameen/" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;border-radius:25px;"></a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/AbdullahAmeenn?lang=en" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;border-radius:25px;"></a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
</nav>
```

Comment: If you can add your css code too, we would be able to help you. Seems like it should be the padding of the item above a tag is causing it, its just a wild guess. Could you please add css too or a working example?

Comment: can you share snippet demo?

Comment: Sure, however there are several html pages, images (maps) and PDF files that are linked to this project so I can not share the whole project, but what I can do I already shared the navbar code and the whole CSS file here:

https://codepen.io/AbdullahAmeen/pen/MWweKPv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light fixed-top p-0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below style:

```
.navbar.scrolled .navbar-collapse{
    background: #116980;
    margin: -15px;
    padding: 15px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The above lines would assign background color to `.navbar-collapse` when scrolled down. However since `.navbar-collapse` contains margin, the above code would **remove the margin and change it to padding** while **move `.navbar-collapse` to back** to prevent it from covering .navbar-brand and .navbar-toggler.

Comment: Thanks for this. I added the above code to my style.css file and it doesn't change anything. I still have that problem.

Comment: Thank you Aluminium Shek and Juan Garcia! Finally I followed both of the recommendations and the problem is solved now. Here is what I did:
HTML:

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light fixed-top p-0">

CSS:
.navbar-light{
    background-color:transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 65px;
}
.navbar-light.scrolled {
    background-color:#116980;
}

.navbar.scrolled .navbar-collapse{
    background: #116980;
    z-index: -1;
}